# get child elements inside div ? java script

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<div id="mess">
 <h1>Bhashyam School</h1>
 <p>AC Nagar Main Road, Nellore <br>Ho, Nellore - 524001  </p>
 <p class="tel">Telephone: +(91)-9603444376</p>
</div>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send.php" onsubmit="this.divcontent.value = document.getElementById('mess').innerHTML;">
    <p>
    <input id="box" type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number. ex:988*******"><input type="hidden" name="divcontent" id="divcontent" value="" /> <button type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">Get Sms</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Hello Friends we are developing sms form, i want to grab elements `h1`, `p` & `p class=tel` inside of `<div id="mess">` when form has been submit (onsubmit event)

What is the correct javascript code to get element inside div tag elements?

Comment: provide demo of your code : jsfiddle.net

Comment: You want the *elements*, or the text *from* those elements?

Comment: why dont you use **hidden** input textbox ??

Comment: provide us ur js code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working demo of what you asked

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7dxs/5/)

What I have done is added string to hidden field `divcontent` inside form

and updated `onsubmit` of form with

```
onsubmit="return getChilds();"
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mess">
    <h1>Bhashyam School</h1>
    <p>AC Nagar Main Road, Nellore <br/>Ho, Nellore - 524001  </p>
    <p class="tel">Telephone: +(91)-9603444376 </p>
</div>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send.php" onsubmit="return getChilds();">
    <p>
        <input id="box" type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number. ex:988*******"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="divcontent" id="divcontent" value="" /> 
        <button type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">Get Sms</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getChilds()
    {
        var arr=document.getElementById('mess').childNodes, str='';
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i].innerHTML!=undefined) {
                str+=" "+(arr[i].textContent||arr[i].innerText);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("divcontent").value=str;
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

better you should have some `input` with type `hidden` so hold such data and which is safe and better way of doing this task.

but why don't you go with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this, it offers better and cleaner way for doing many stuffs.

Comment: where to add your java code in head or onsubmit="?"  function getChilds()
{
    var arr=document.getElementById('mess').childNodes;
    console.log(arr);
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
           alert(arr[i].innerHTML);
}

Comment: just add this in your html with script, I am updating code.

Comment: check this link: http://deluxewebwise.in/lab3/

Comment: I guess you didn't noticed I have updated code and fiddle link @user2734770 see latest code it will give you only data out of that.

Comment: i want data: Bhashyam School

AC Nagar Main Road, Nellore 
Ho, Nellore - 524001

Telephone: +(91)-9603444376 to be delivered to the number entered in the text area box...

Comment: can you come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50321/dream

Comment: i don't have 20 reputation?

Comment: please help in this..

Comment: ohh sorry! I didn't noticed that so what exactly you want here, do you want to combine whole result in one string?

Comment: yes , http://deluxewebwise.in/lab3/

Comment: see my update code now with fiddle updated and if it helps you don't forget to accept my answer :-)

Comment: i want data to be delivered to the mobile number entered. please have a look the form: http://deluxewebwise.in/lab3/

Comment: do you want form to be submitted with that string? if yes then have a look at updated code and fiddle. @user2734770

Comment: In the above java code i want childNodes with particular class names (ex:p class="tel", p class="email"),.....that's it

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload= function(){
  var elems = [];
  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
    var nodes = document.getElementById('mess').childNodes;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < nodes.length; i++){
      if (nodes[i].nodeType == 1){
          elems.push(nodes[i].innerHTML);
      }
    }
    //console.log(elems);
  }
}
```

`elems` contains what u want

Comment: how to add this code?

Comment: @user2734770 this piece of code populate the data into variable `elems` on form submission..what u want to achive?

Comment: check this link: http://deluxewebwise.in/lab3/

Comment: i want data: Bhashyam School AC Nagar Main Road, Nellore Ho, Nellore - 524001 Telephone: +(91)-9603444376 to be delivered to the number entered in the text area box

Comment: @user2734770 u want all those data into the text input box?

Comment: data to be delivered to the number entered..

Comment: what is the exact code...